# How to fix permission error of Ebs volume using Amazon Data lifecycle manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, terraform, amazon-iam

I applied the terraform code in this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dlm_lifecycle_policy), which contains code to apply the specific roles and permission s to service dlm lifecycle for ebs volumes.

But still I am getting access errors.

[image: error]

Please share any suggestions on how to fix this.

Few more steps I tried.
With policy actions set to all ec2 permissions ("ec2:*"), snapshots are created without error.

But if I tried below permissions, which I got from default policy created when attempted to create lifecycle from webconsole.

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateSnapshots",
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
                "ec2:EnableFastSnapshotRestores",
                "ec2:DescribeFastSnapshotRestores",
                "ec2:DisableFastSnapshotRestores",
                "ec2:CopySnapshot",
                "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshotAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshotTierStatus",
                "ec2:ModifySnapshotTier"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

With above permissions, it is not working.
Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The terraform code may be out of date, the permissions in the default role created via console should work, but there are multiple permissions statements in that default role. You may be missing permissions for DLM to create tags:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*"
}
```